# Are there local maxima in the standard 2-pl model or is there proof that there aren't?

Tags: logistic, mathematical-statistics, item-response-theory

I'm looking to use iterative logistic regression to find the parameter values of the 2 pl model:
$
P = \sigma(\alpha_{i} (\theta_{s} - \beta_{i}))
$ where
$
\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}
$

I know how to proof that in normal logistic regression the log likelihood of the data is concave and that there will thus be no local maxima in the regression. 
As an extension of this if I keep $\alpha_{i}$ and $\beta_{i}$ in the model above constant, I can obtain $\theta_{s}$ without running into local maxima and vice versa. My question though is if there could be local maxima over the whole space of paramaters and if not, how to proof this.

**Edit:**

Some clarification for those not familiar with IRT and the 2PL model.
The 2PL model gives a probability ($P$) that student $s$ will correctly answer item $i$. There is thus an $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameter for every item and a $\theta$ parameter for every student. Every datapoint is one question that is either answered correctly or incorrectly and the only parameters that influences the prediction $P$ for this datapoint is the parameters of the student $s$ and the item $i$ involved in that question. 
What is looked for are values for all the parameters such that the likelihood of the data ($\prod_{d \in D} P_{d}^{t_d}  (1- P_{d})^{1-t_d}$ where D are all the datapoints and t is 1 if the question was answered correctly or 0 otherwise) is maximized.

It is known that the solution is not unique due to the nature of the model. My question is if there are local maxima in $\prod_{d \in D} P_{d}^{t_d}  (1- P_{d})^{1-t_d}$ and if not how this can be proven.

Comment: What does "2-pl" mean? Since your expression for $P$ does not seem to involve any data at all, how is it a model?

Comment: [2PL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory#Number_of_IRT_parameters) is a standard item response theory model. Every datapoint concerns one student answering one question. Parameters with subscript $i$ belong to that specific question, the parameter with subscript $s$ belong to that specific student.
The data used in the logistic regression will be very sparse, as only the parameters belonging to the student answering and the question asked will be non-zero for every datapoint. I hope that clarifies a bit what an IRT model and its data look like.

Comment: Thank you, that does help--but it does not eliminate the cryptic and likely incorrect nature of $P$, which still does not involve any data (because you to refer to $\alpha_i, \beta_i$, and $\theta_s$ as parameters and those are its sole arguments). If you would like something proven you must take some care to make sure it is stated clearly and correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this and am still not sure what exactly is needed to make it clear. I made an edit to the problem and hope it now contains all the necessary information. Thanks for your help in clearing it up!

Comment: Your problem seems to be notational. The data are not just zeros and ones: they are a collection of triples $(i,s,d)$ where $i$ designates an item, $s$ a student, and $d\in\{0,1\}$ the response. The likelihood of each triple is $p(i,s)^d(1-p(i,s))^{1-d}$ where $p(i,s)=\sigma(\alpha_i(\theta_s-\beta_i))$. The likelihood function is the product of these likelihoods. It differs from logistic regression in that $p(i,s)$ is a *multilinear* function of the parameters (rather than linear). (This observation points towards a solution.) But shouldn't the last line read "minima" instead of "maxima"?

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed exactly what's going on and the question is if using this particular bilinear function the log likelihood is still concave.
I can see where the confusion on minima comes from and will leave out the minus in front of the log to make it consistent throughout the question.